# Structure of Express application with Redis

Tags: node.js, express, redis, node.js-connect

I am unsure about where would be the best place to define the redis client in a Express application I am building.  I am using [skeleton](https://github.com/EtienneLem/skeleton) as the framework.

It seems like the connection to redis should go in either `boot.coffee` or `app.coffee`, but then I can't easily get a reference to it in `application_controller.coffee`, which is where I need it.

If I put `client = redis.createClient` in `application_controller.coffee`, will that mean a new client is created on each request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define the Redis client in `app.coffee` (after configuration, before the routes) and set the Redis client as a property on the App object:
`app.client = redis.createClient`

Then in `application_controller.coffee` you can access the Redis client by `app.client`.